# How can I sort in (n)hibernate on a property of a child object?

Tags: nhibernate, sorting, criteria

I have an object from my domain model that has a child object.  How can I use a criteria query to order based on a property of the child?

For example:

```
class FooType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public BarType Bar { get; set; }
}

class BarType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

...

// WORKS GREAT
var orderedByName = _session.CreateCriteria<FooType>().AddOrder(Order.Asc("Name")).List();

// THROWS "could not resolve property: Bar.Color of: FooType"
var orderedByColor = _session.CreateCriteria<FooType>().AddOrder(Order.Asc("Bar.Color")).List();
```

What do I need to do to enable this scenario?  I'm using NHibernate 2.1.  Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to either add an alias or create a nested criteria for your child. Not sure how to do this in NHibernate, in Hibernate it's done via `createCriteria()` and `createAlias()` methods.
You would then use the alias as prefix in order by.

**Update** Hibernate code sample:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(FooType.class);
criteria.createAlias("bar", "b");
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("b.color"));
```

I imagine in NHibernate it would be quite similar, though with property/entity names uppercased. Here's [an example](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-examples) from NHibernate documentation.

Comment: Can you give me a code sample?  I'm not sure I understand what you mean.