# Sorting by nested property (three levels) in Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm having trouble trying to order a Criteria by a property that is nested several levels.

I've read the answer [How can I sort in (n)hibernate on a property of a child object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269177/how-can-i-sort-in-nhibernate-on-a-property-of-a-child-object/1269211#1269211) and saw that creating an alias might be the solution.

This works fine for one level. But if I try order by a property nested two or three levels, I get an error. My code is as follows:

```
@Entity
class TareaAsignada ... {
    Siniestro siniestro;
    ...
}

@Entity
class Siniestro ... {
    UsuarioSIS dueno;
    ...
}

@Entity
class UsuarioSIS ... {
    Agencia agencia;
    ...
}

@Entity
class Agencia ... {
    String nombre;
    ...
}
```

The code I'm using to create the Criteria is:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(TareaAsignada.class);
...
criteria.createAlias("siniestro", "siniestro");
criteria.createAlias("siniestro.dueno", "dueno");
criteria.createAlias("dueno.agencia", "agencia");
...
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("siniestro.dueno.agencia.nombre"));
```

The error I get is:

```
could not resolve property: dueno.agencia.nombre of: com.example.siniestro.model.Siniestro
```

Comment: Use the alias name you created instead of the complete path.

Comment: It yields: could not resolve property: agencia of: com.example.siniestro.tarea.model.TareaAsignada

Comment: Hmm, thats strange. Usually if all the alias are created correctly `Order.asc("agencia.nombre")` should work.

Comment: My bad, you were correct :).